# Excel - VBA Show Hide Specific Columns - While sheet and workbook are protected

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using some VBA to toggle showing and hiding columns, currently this is working on consecutive columns `D:H` however I'd like to selectively pick which columns this should work on.

The code I'm using is :

```
Private Sub ShowHide_Click()
Dim xAddress As String
xAddress = "D:H"
If ShowHide.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
    ShowHide.Caption = "Hide"
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
    ShowHide.Caption = "Show"
End If
End Sub
```

How do I change this so it doesn't just work on D to H but allows me to chose the specific columns I want to show/hide ?  ie: D,E,H,J,M,L

I did try changing the xAddress to `D,E,H,J,M,L` but that generated a debug error.

Also when the Worksheet and Workbook are protected this fails to work. Is there anyway way to use this while they are protected ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Range("D")` does not mean anything for VBA. `Range("D,E")` neither.
   But `Range("D:E,H:H,J:J,M:M,L:L")` should work...
2. You cannot hide columns in a protected sheet. If you do not know the password to unprotect, there is nothing to be done. But, if you know it, you can unprotect it (in code), do the job and protect the sheet after hiding-unhiding the necessary columns. Something like:

```
Sub UnprotectHideDiscontColumnsRange()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, pass As String
    
    pass = ""            'use here the necessary password to unprotect-protect
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
    sh.Unprotect pass
    sh.Range("D:E,H:H,J:J,M:M,L:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True '/False
    sh.Protect pass
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise you had to specify the sheets as `H:H` etc. Does including the password in the VBA cause any issues with security ?  Is there anyway it can be found out ?

Comment: @Tom Not sure I've got you... If you know the password, no any issue. VBA is designed to deal with sheet protection password as shown above.

Comment: sorry I meant could someone extract the password from the spreadsheet ?

Comment: @Tom Is this somehow connected to your question? In principle, everything can be hacked. Until the last Excel versions it was something extremely simple. Now it is much more complicated to break the password, but nobody can say that it cannot be broken...

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this

```
Sub ShowHide_Click()
Dim xAddress As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.Unprotect "Password"

xAddress = "A:B,D:E,G:H,Q:Q"

ws.Range(xAddress).EntireColumn.Hidden = True


End Sub
```